# Did the Federation have installations inside gas giants?

Tags: star-trek

We see operations on various planets, but what about gas giants? Did the Federation have any floating installations *inside* (e.g. not just in orbit of) those planets?

Comment: Inside, or in orbit of? https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jupiter_Station

Comment: Today I learned that the term "Gas Giant" was invented by Star Trek author James Blish

Comment: @Valorum more inside of.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it more focused, otherwise someone (probably me) is just going to list fifty space stations *in orbit of* gas giants and none inside.

Comment: @Valorum honestly, I should just expand this to include other extreme environments, like underwater stations too.

Comment: That sounds like a second question to me. No sense cluttering this one